# Howto implement Spring Security User/Authorities with Hibernate/JPA2?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, spring-security

I am trying to implement DAOs to work with Spring Security database authentication in Hibernate/JPA2. Spring uses following relations and associations in order to represent user & roles:

[image]

repesented as postgresql create query:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  username character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  "password" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  enabled boolean NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (username)
);
CREATE TABLE authorities
(
  username character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  authority character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_authorities_users FOREIGN KEY (username)
      REFERENCES users (username) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Using the on-board implementations of `GrantedAuthorities`, `UserDetailsService` and `UserDetailsmanager`, everything is fine. However, I am not satisfied with the JDBC implementation of Spring and would like to write my own ones. In order to do so, I tried to create a representation of the relations by following business objects:

The user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username"})})
public class AppUser implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8275492272371421013L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "appUser"
    )
    private Set<AppAuthority> appAuthorities;

    @Column(name = "accountNonExpired")
    private Boolean accountNonExpired;

    @Column(name = "accountNonLocked")
    private Boolean accountNonLocked;

    @Column(name = "credentialsNonExpired")
    private Boolean credentialsNonExpired;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "personalinformation_fk", nullable = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private PersonalInformation personalInformation;

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Boolean enabled;

    public AppUser(
            String username,
            String password,
            boolean enabled,
            boolean accountNonExpired,
            boolean credentialsNonExpired,
            boolean accountNonLocked,
            Collection<? extends AppAuthority> authorities,
            PersonalInformation personalInformation
    ) {
        if (((username == null) || "".equals(username)) || (password == null)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor");
        }

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.accountNonExpired = accountNonExpired;
        this.credentialsNonExpired = credentialsNonExpired;
        this.accountNonLocked = accountNonLocked;
        this.appAuthorities = Collections.unmodifiableSet(sortAuthorities(authorities));
        this.personalInformation = personalInformation;
    }

    public AppUser() {
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public PersonalInformation getPersonalInformation() {
        return personalInformation;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setPersonalInformation(PersonalInformation personalInformation) {
        this.personalInformation = personalInformation;
    }

    // Getters, setters 'n other stuff
```

And the authority entity as an implementation of GrantedAuthorities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
public class AppAuthority implements GrantedAuthority, Serializable {
    //~ Instance fields ================================================================================================

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "authority", nullable = false)
    private String authority;

    // Here comes the buggy attribute. It is supposed to repesent the
    // association username<->username, but I just don't know how to
    // implement it 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "appuser_fk")
    private AppUser appUser;

    //~ Constructors ===================================================================================================

    public AppAuthority(String username, String authority) {
        Assert.hasText(authority,
                "A granted authority textual representation is required");
        this.username = username;
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public AppAuthority() {
    }

    // Getters 'n setters 'n other stuff
```

My problem is the `@ManyToOne` assoc. of `AppAuthorities`: It is supposed to be "username", but trying and doing so throws an error, because I've got to typify that attribute as `String` ... while Hibernate expects the associated entity. So what I tryied is actually providing the correct entity and creating the association by `@JoinColumn(name = "appuser_fk")`. This is, of course, rubbish, because in order to load the User, I will have the foreign key in `username`, while Hibernate searches for it in `appuser_fk`, which will always be empty.

So here is my question: any suggestion on how to modify the above metioned code in order to get a correct JPA2 implementation of the data model?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You `AppAuthority` doesn't need `username` at all. Spring Security can't depend on it because it depends on the [`GrantedAuthority` interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html) which doesn't have any methods to access username.

But the better practice is to decouple your domain model from Spring Security. When you have a custom `UserDetailsService`, you don't need to mimic neither Spring Security's default database schema nor its object model. Your `UserDetailsService` can load your own `AppUser` and `AppAuthority` and then create `UserDetails` and `GrantedAuthority`s based on them. This leads to cleaner design with better separation of concerns.

Comment: Ah! That's great news! I shall proceed precisely as you suggest, thanks.

Comment: can you share project url? i already wasted my 5 days for make one module using spring boot security rest api with oauth2. the problem is when i call url is giving false data like  "authorities": null,
        "accountNonExpired": false,
        "accountNonLocked": false,
        "credentialsNonExpired": false,
        "enabled": false.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the classic Hibernate problem of using a domain-specific key.  A possible fix would be to create a new primary key field; e.g. `userId int` for the `Users` and `Authorities` entities / tables, remove `Authorities.userName`, and change `Users.userName` to a unique secondary key.

Comment: Hi. Your solution was my first guess, and if it wasn't for Spring, I would have used it (actually, if I had designed this data model, I'd *always* used int ids). However, I fear that with all that convention-over-configuration, *removing* attributes may have unpredictable side-effects on the rest of the Spring Security Framework. What if some Spring Sec. beans rely on Authorities.userName? Sure, I could re-implement them, but is there no other solution leaving my data model untouched? All in all, I do expect a ORM framework to adopt to a given data model, and not the other way round ...

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way that decouples the UserDetailsService from JPA/Hibernate.

You can model your User and Authority class as you like and use this while defining userDetailsService in configuration:-

```
<sec:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="webDS"
                id="userDetailsService"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT USER_NAME,PASSWORD,TRUE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE USER_NAME=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT c.USER_NAME,r.ROLE_NAME from CUSTOMER c 
                                          JOIN CUSTOMER_ROLE cr ON c.CUSTOMER_ID = cr.CUSTOMER_ID 
                                          JOIN ROLE r ON cr.ROLE_ID = r.ROLE_ID 
                                          WHERE USER_NAME=?" />
```

This way you can define fine tuned SQL query to fetch user and roles from your database.
All you need to take care of is the table and column name.