# Spring Security - extended user class

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm developing a system using Spring Security, JPA/Hibernate, Postgres JSF and Primefaces.

There are three classes that extending user class, pilot, mechanic and staff. But if I extend it won't be neither class or table user to authenticate.

I put a OneToOne relationship between classes.

Somebody has some diferent idea to do this?

Comment: This question is a bit unclear...but, at a minimum, you should start with custom user details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607696/spring-security-custom-userdetails.  If you need to extend beyond simple data, use OneToOne: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696680/howto-implement-spring-security-user-authorities-with-hibernate-jpa2